# Names of bones in Dope Sheet have very faint text color and yellow background color

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I have this problem as described in the title. It might be a dumb question but is this issue common? And how to fix it? I know I can change the text color but I think that probably will be the last move.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find your culprit in here, in Blender Preferences -> Themes -> Dope Sheet.

[image]

Comment: I didn't change any settings about that and I tried creating a new armature and found out text in that armature was fine. So I guess it's the problem of the armature that this addon creates, which is a addon that generates a standard UE4 mannequin. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Theme space list]

For anyone with the same question, its the 'Theme space list' option under the dope sheet settings in preferences. Change the source list text or highlight to see the letters